# How to stop content from stacking on top of each other?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been creating a blog and I have made these cards but I want the content to stack side by side rather than on top of each other.

Here's an image:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjsnP.jpg

**model.py**

```
class ProjectPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
def projects(request):
    ProjectPosts = ProjectPost.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/projects.html', {'projectposts': ProjectPosts})
```

**projects.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="text-right">
                    <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}"><h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></h1></a>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-10 ">
                    {% for projectpost in projectposts %}
                    <div class="projectposts">
                        <img src="{{ projectpost.image_url }}" id="projects_image" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                        <div class="page-header">
                            <h2>{{ projectpost.title }}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <footer>By: {{ projectpost.author }}</footer>
                        <p>{{ projectpost.text | truncatewords:50 }}</p>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Impossible to answer (without an unreasonably broad answer) without knowing the code/styles you're using.

Comment: Sorry, just added them in.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrapped your for loop inside a `col-lg-3 ...`. You need to put the column classes inside the loop, not outside it:

```
<div class="row">
    {% for projectpost in projectposts %}
    <!-- These columns need to be inside the for loop -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-10 ">
        <div class="projectposts">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

You may be able to remove one level of nesting and just put all your classes in one `<div class="projectposts col-lg-3 col-md-3...">`.